# Room. error: Multiple fields have the same columnName

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-room

I am trying to create relation between tables where one of the tables references another one twice. Here is the code:

```
@Entity(tableName = "message",
        foreignKeys = [
            ForeignKey(entity = Contact::class,
                    parentColumns = ["id"],
                    childColumns = ["toContactId"],
                    onDelete = NO_ACTION
            ),
            ForeignKey(entity = Contact::class,
                    parentColumns = ["id"],
                    childColumns = ["fromContactId"],
                    onDelete = NO_ACTION)
        ], indices = [Index("toContactId"), Index("fromContactId")]
)
data class Message(
        @PrimaryKey var id: String,
        var creationDate: Date,
        var messageStatus: MessageStatus,
        var toContactId: String,
        var fromContactId: String,
        var text: String
)


@Entity(tableName = "contact")
data class Contact(
        @PrimaryKey val id: String,
        val firstName: String,
        val lastName: String,
        val cellPhone: String,
        val email: String
)
```

And here is how I have created "relation" class:

```
data class MessageRelations(@Embedded var message: Message,
                                @Embedded var toContact: Contact,
                                @Embedded var fromContact: Contact)
```

This approach results in
**error: Multiple fields have the same columnName: id. Field names: message > id, toContact > id, fromContact > id.**

I also tried to add prefixes to annotation **@Embedded(prefix = "to_")** and **@Embedded(prefix = "from_")**. But in this case Room can't find matches between fileds returned by the query and those in *MessageRelations* class.

I'll be grateful for any hint on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleieve that using [**@Relation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Relation) instead of **@Embed** will resolve those issues as rather than including the fields/variables from the Entity it builds the object according to the relationship.

So you would have something like :-

```
data class MessageRelations(@Embedded var message: Message,
                                @Relation(parentColumn = "toContactId", entityColumn = "id") var toContact: Contact,
                                @Relation(parentColumn = "fromContactId", entityColumn = "id") var fromContact: Contact)
```

- **Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested or run**.

Comment: should I still specify ForeignKey in Message entity when using @Relation?

Comment: @OlehLiskovych yes (although there is no need to as Foreign Keys primarily define a rule for insertions/updates/deletions, rather making a relationship happen). Perhaps have a look at [Which approach should i go for regarding relations in Room DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542439/which-approach-should-i-go-for-regarding-relations-in-room-db/59544425#59544425)

Comment: Awesome. Just change "albumId" to "id". Thank you for answer and further explanations!

Comment: @OlehLiskovych ooops thought I'd changed that (will edit the answer accordingly).